# Angular JS: Inserting Row into MySQL Database by JSON doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql, angular, ionic-framework

i am working with the Ionic Framework in Angular JS on an little application for mobile devices. I am trying to add a row into MySQL - which doesnt work.

**question.ts:**

```
   createEntry(questionid : Int32Array, questionanswer : Int32Array) : void
   {
      let headers   : any       = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
          options   : any       = { "key" : "create", "user" : 'test', "questionid" : questionid, "questionanswer" : questionanswer },
          url       : any       = "http://www.so-ta.de/brkwrkt2018/manage-data.php";

      this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(options), headers)
      .subscribe((data : any) =>
      {

         this.sendNotification(`Answer for ${questionid} added`);
      },
      (error : any) =>
      {
        this.sendNotification(`Error`);
      });
   }
```

**manage-data.php:**

```
 switch($key)
   {

      case "create":

         $user              = filter_var($obj->user, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
         $questionid        = filter_var($obj->questionid, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
         $questionanswer    = filter_var($obj->questionanswer, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);

         try {
            $sql    = "INSERT INTO fragen_antworten(user, questionid, questionanswer) VALUES(:user, :questionid, :questionanswer)";
            $stmt   = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':questionid', $questionid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':questionanswer', $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();

            echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Congratulations the record user: ' . $user . ' | questionid' . $questionid . ' | questionanswer ' . $questionanswer . ' was added to the database'));
         }
         catch(PDOException $e)
         {
            echo $e->getMessage();
         }

      break;
   }
```

The given values questionid and questionanswer are all ok and printed out correctly. My Question is: How can I get a error-message which helps me finding the problem? Is it the php-file or js-file? :-( Heeeelp me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will not throw so your errors will never be returned.

`$stmt->execute()` will return true or false, depending on if successful. If false, you can get your error message with `$pdo->errorInfo()`.

Comment: Ok, it gives me the following error: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 19. "["00000",null,null]SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'questionanswer' cannot be null". But how can it be null? Before this error its printing me questionID = 2 and answer = 4. Thank you for your help, Clint.

Comment: @Montero Well, that would be because in your echo you print `$questionanswer` but in your query you bind `$description`